# org.apache.axis.AxisFault not found, even though I've setup my maven dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, axis

I'm new to maven, Java, and all things jar'y.  I initially created an Eclipse Java project without maven, and added org.apache.axis jar files manually (they exist on my hard drive).  This allowed me to run and debug in Eclipse.  Then, I learned about maven and converted the project to maven so that I can automate the build.  I understand my next step is to set all of the dependencies properly.  I was able to add a few without a problem, but I get an error with org.apache.axis.AxisFault.

Here is my dependency in the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I get a successful build on the command line `mvn package`, but when I attempt to run my `main` rountine (`java -cp target/mything-0.0.1.jar me.mything.TestApp`), I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axis/AxisFault
    at me.mything.TestApp.main(TestApp.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis.AxisFault
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
...
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try to take another version..

Comment: Clean your project using maven clean and try again, it might solve your problem.

Comment: I've tried maven clean, and no luck.  Also, I've tried other versions.  I can see the AxisFault class in the ~/.m2/.../axis.jar file.  My rookie is showing through, but do I simply need to set my classpath to ~/.m2/?  I assumed maven would bundle the jars, but maybe it doesn't work that way.